# Compiling executable from .pro

Tags: c++

I have a folder which has some source in it, that should be ready to compile. The folder has a .pro file in it, which seems to be the compiling file, but how do I use it? I'm trying to create an .exe from it.

Comment: The project is done in qt?

Comment: Please take some time to read [ask].

Comment: Umm i have not done this, but i guess it is. It has alot of different files mainly .cpp and .h but some .rc too

Answer (score 0):

The *.pro file normally stands for a project in an IDE. 
Since you have the resources file (.rc) it seems the project has been done in Qt Creator.

You can try to download the Qt Creator (and install it) and then by using

> File -> Open File or Project

navigate to that .pro file and open it. You can then configure the project and build it.

If the project was not done in Qt, then you will need to be more specific about the problem ...

Comment: Thank you very much :) I'll try this and if not, i'll let you know.

Comment: 'CC' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Makefile.Release:474: recipe for target 'C:/Users/tumppi/Desktop/GPU-Coin-master/src/leveldb/libleveldb.a' failed
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/tumppi/Desktop/build-Gpu-qt-Desktop_Qt_5_8_0_MinGW_32bit-Release'
mingw32-make[1]: *** [C:/Users/tumppi/Desktop/GPU-Coin-master/src/leveldb/libleveldb.a]

Comment: Error 1
Makefile:34: recipe for target 'release' failed
mingw32-make: *** [release] Error 2
04:20:06: The process "C:\Qt\Tools\mingw530_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project Gpu-qt (kit: Desktop Qt 5.8.0 MinGW 32bit)
When executing step "Make"

Comment: Oh, i think im missing some files myself wich are included in the code..

Comment: You have to change the compiler. You want to use CC which is not found on your computer. I don't know if you're using Linux or Windows so I cannot tell you how exactly solve it. 
But to compile it you would need a working compiler on your system and you should tell Qt (project specs) where to find that compiler on your system. 
Check this link: http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-configuring.html

Comment: and for the kits for building the project also look at this
http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-targets.html

Comment: Also i have MinGW installed wich should be able to compile this, i dont know though.

Comment: C:/Qt/Tools/mingw530_32/bin/mingw32-make -f Makefile.Release
mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/tumppi/Desktop/build-Gpu-qt-Desktop_Qt_5_8_0_MinGW_32bit-Release'
cd C:/Users/tumppi/Desktop/GPU-Coin-master/src/leveldb && CC=gcc CXX=g++ TARGET_OS=OS_WINDOWS_CROSSCOMPILE C:/Qt/Tools/mingw530_32/bin/mingw32-make OPT="-pipe -fno-keep-inline-dllexport -O2" libleveldb.a libmemenv.a && ranlib C:/Users/tumppi/Desktop/GPU-Coin-master/src/leveldb/libleveldb.a && ranlib C:/Users/tumppi/Desktop/GPU-Coin-master/src/leveldb/libmemenv.a
This is right before the CC is not recognized

Comment: try creating a new project in Qt Creator and building it. If you have the same problems, then MinGW is not installed correctly or not recognised by Qt Creator. Try finding a tutorial for it. or use another compiler (I'm using msvc for example).

Comment: if the answer helped in opening the .pro file, then please accept it to help others.
And about the compiling, I hope you managed to figure something out?